# geb.page content module cannot be resolved

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, automation, geb, intellij-14

Hi i tried to do a NavigationModule to acces to my content in geb.page, but when i want to instance from this navigation 'module' cannot be resolved by intellij

```
class NavigationModule extends Module{
    static content = {
        homeLink { $("a", title:"Home") }
        contactLink { $("a", title:"Contact Us") }
    }
}

class HomePage extends Page{

    static url = "http://www.websitetest.com"
    static at={
        assert $("h1").text() == "Test website speed and performance"
    }
    static content = {
        navBar {module NavigationModule}
        //loginLink { $("a", text: "login")[0]}
    }
}
```

and also I can't access from my script

```
void test() {

    Browser.drive() {
        to HomePage
        navBar.
    }
}
```

someone know what happen? I spent a lot of time searching in google but i don't find anything

thanks in advance

Comment: there is always the possibility, that intellij does not understand a DSL.

Answer (score 1):

The Geb doc (http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/ide-and-typing.html#strong_typing) recommends to expecitly define Types to have a better IDE support.

With this example code completion works for me.

```
class HomePage extends Page {

    static url = "http://www.websitetest.com"
    static at={
        assert $("h1").text() == "Test website speed and performance"
    }

    static content = {
        navBar {module NavigationModule}
        //loginLink { $("a", text: "login")[0]}
    }

    // explicitly define getter to give IntelliJ more type information
    NavigationModule getNav() {
        navBar
    }
}
```

Test script:

```
void test() {

    Browser.drive() {
        // assign to page in order to have code completion on page
        page = to HomePage
        // code completin for homeLink works
        navBar.homeLink
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jörg Alferink the way that you give is good works fine, in fact my error was that text value is wrong the correctly value is "Login" with capital leter :S lol , but looks fine the explicit way is more understandably. thanks a lot